# Bootstrap DatePicker, how to set the start date for tomorrow?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I set the startDate for tomorrow? I don't see an option in the documentation for Date.today so I can add one more day.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```js
$(function() {
    $("#appointment_adate").datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-d',
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: '+1d'    
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see a datepicker in bootstrap. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html ?

Comment: There is such a datepicker http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ and http://vitalets.github.com/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: Here is the link: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There is no official datepicker for bootstrap; as such, you should explicitly state which one you're using.

If you're using [eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), there's a [startDate](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/ca11c450/README.md#startdate) option.  As discussed directly under the [Options section](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/ca11c450/README.md#options) in the README:

> All options that take a "Date" can handle a Date object; a String formatted according to the given format; **or a timedelta relative to today**, eg '-1d', '+6m +1y', etc, where valid units are 'd' (day), 'w' (week), 'm' (month), and 'y' (year).

So you would do:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: '+1d'
})
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but it did not work for me, I added my code in my original post.

Comment: My apologies it worked. I was confused with the todayHighlight, who selects the current date.

Comment: I used `startDate: new Date()` to select today

Comment: Can you please indicate the full reference of `timedeltas` url?

Answer (score 22):

If you are talking about [Datepicker for bootstrap](http://vitalets.github.com/bootstrap-datepicker/), you set the start date (the min date) by using the following:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', <DATETIME STRING HERE>);
```

Comment: this worked for me with laravel

Answer (score 9):

```
this.$('#datepicker').datepicker({minDate: 1});
```

`minDate:0` - Enable dates in the calender from the current date. `MinDate:1` enable dates in the calender `currentDate+1`

To Restrict date between from tomorrow and the same day next month u need to give something like

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 1, maxDate: "+1M" });
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) you may use this style:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', "01-01-1900");
```

Answer (score -1):

1) use for tommorow's date
    startDate: '+1d'

2) use for yesterday's date
    startDate: '-1d'

3) use for today's date
    startDate: new Date()