# bootstrap-datepicker start date limit

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap date picker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker). I would like to set start limit of datepicker (I want to restrict going back date from today.). I have read documentation and related answers on stackoverflow ([Bootstrap DatePicker, how to set the start date for tomorrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409779/bootstrap-datepicker-how-to-set-the-start-date-for-tomorrow)) but could not set start date.

My codes:

Html:

```
<input name="endDate" class="datepicker form-control pull-right" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy" value="19.05.2016">
```

Javascript:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    language: 'tr',
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: '+1d' //for just test
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working correctly, but you just don't see it because you are on next month. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40yfcgw7/)

By setting `value="19.05.2016"`you set the default selected day to 19.05.2016, thus you are on May motnh tab. The option `startDate: '+1d'` set the default selectable period to start from `+1d` from **today**.
That's pretty clear in the Fiddle, if you look at what date is set as value and how many days are added in startDate option.