# How to set start date in Bootstrap datepicker to existing value?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I know how to set a default date using either the current date or a fixed date. But how can I get the calendar to display the date that already may exist my date field?

I.e. if the date in the field is 09/15/2001 how can I get the calendar to go to that date when it opens?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', '2012-01-01');
```

More info here: [Bootstrap DatePicker, how to set the start date for tomorrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409779/bootstrap-datepicker-how-to-set-the-start-date-for-tomorrow)

Comment: That sets a fixed date but does not use the date value already in the field. Again, it's not so much about setting the date but what date is displayed when the calendar opens.

Comment: Maybe the startView?

Comment: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/ca11c450/README.md#startview

Comment: that is where it is set but I cannot get it to take a variable
or find any other way to pass the value that does not break the datepicker. I need something like:

`  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                autoclose: true,
                immediateUpdates: false,
                todayHighlight: true,
                defaultDate: CURRENT VALUE IN FIELD
            });
        });
    </script>'

Comment: So you need to get the date from the field in the right date format.

Comment: Something like defaultDate: $('.myField').val()